# Developing an MCA component for OpenMPI: how to progress MPI_Recv using custom BTL for NIC under development?

Tags: mpi, openmpi

I'm trying to develop a btl for a custom NIC. I studied the btl.h file to understand the flow of calls that are expected to be implemented in my component. I'm using a simple test (which works like a charm with the TCP btl) to test my development, the code is a simple MPI_Send + MPI_Recv:

```
  int ping_pong_count = 1;
  int partner_rank = (world_rank + 1) % 2;
  printf("MY RANK: %d PARTNER: %d\n",world_rank,partner_rank);
    if (world_rank == 0) {
      // Increment the ping pong count before you send it
      ping_pong_count++;
      MPI_Send(&ping_pong_count, 1, MPI_INT, partner_rank, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
      printf("%d sent and incremented ping_pong_count %d to %d\n",
             world_rank, ping_pong_count, partner_rank);
    } else {
      MPI_Recv(&ping_pong_count, 1, MPI_INT, partner_rank, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
      printf("%d received ping_pong_count %d from %d\n",
             world_rank, ping_pong_count, partner_rank);
    }
  MPI_Finalize();
}
```

I see that in my component's btl code the functions called during the "MPI_send" phase are:

1. **mca_btl_mycomp_add_procs**
2. **mca_btl_mycomp_prepare_src**
3. **mca_btl_mycomp_send** (where I set the return to 1, so the send phase
   should be finished)

I see then the print inside the test:

```
0 sent and incremented ping_pong_count 2 to 1
```

and this should conclude the MPI_Send phase.
Then I implemented in the **btl_mycomp_component_progress** function a call to:

```
mca_btl_active_message_callback_t *reg = mca_btl_base_active_message_trigger + tag;
reg->cbfunc(&my_btl->super, &desc);
```

I saw the same code in all the other BTLs and I thought this was enough to unlock the MPI_Recv "polling". But actually I see my test hangs, probably "waiting" for something that never happens (?).

I also took a look in the ob1 **mca_pml_ob1_recv_frag_callback_match** function, and it seems to get to the end of the function, actually matching my frag.

So my question is: how can I say to the framework that I finished my work and so the function can return to the user application? What am I doing wrong?
Is there a way to understand where and what my code is waiting for?

Comment: You'd rather ask this on the devel Open MPI mailing list.

Comment: unfortunately no answer there as well